# WPF application raises Activated event, but the application is not shown and not in focus

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, window, focus

I have two applications. One of them is 3rd party, which sends messages to my WPF app. There are two types of messages: "hide" and "show".

On "hide", my app hides itself with

```
Window window = Application.Current.MainWindow;
window.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
window.Hide();
```

And accordingly on "show" it's shown with:

```
Window window = Application.Current.MainWindow;
if (!window.IsVisible)
    window.Show();
if (window.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
    window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        
window.Activate();
window.Focus();
```

The window itself has subscribed to Activate event. And logs "Application shown" whenever it raised.

Let's say in the 3rd party application it looks like two buttons "Show" and "Hide" accordingly, which user can press at any time. Both applications works on same monitor. My WPF app also has a button "Show 3rd party app", in case it's in front (both apps works in full screen, topmost mode)

The problem is that sometimes (no dependence found why) my application is not shown after user first time press "Show". So he had to press it twice. Though the log contains

> Application shown

two times, each time when user pressed a button.

Also my app subscribed to Deactivated event. It logs "Focus lost" each time event raised.
So I expected my log has also "Focus lost" between two "Application shown", because the 3rd party app should be activated on time user presses button "Show" second time, because focus goes there... But it didn't happen.

Any ideas why?

Any ideas why application is not shown at first time?

Answer (score 2):

I had also similar issue, you need to force it;

```
private void BringToFront(Window window) 
{
    try
    {
        window.Activate();
        window.Topmost = true;  // important
        window.Topmost = false; // important
        window.Focus();

        SystemCommands.RestoreWindow(window);

        window.Activate();
        window.Topmost = true;  // important
        window.Topmost = false; // important
        window.Focus();

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

}
```